# Nginx as http proxy in two different networks and must use udp

Tags: nginx, networking

Dears, I would grateful if you can guide me to solve this problem. I face a challenge, nginx as http proxy in two different networks and must use udp. There are some conditions:

1. Two different networks: A network and B network, they can't connect directly.
2. One proxy server that only support udp: udp-proxy-server, this server have two network interface cards that one is A network and another is B network.
3. Data transfer to A network udp-17002(port) will transfer to B network udp-30001(port) by the udp-proxy-server.

The final target is: client like phone in A network that can call service api successly in B network .

I found that http3 use the udp as the bottom protocol, so I build the nginx that support http3 by the quiche(https://github.com/cloudflare/quiche). I want use the http3 nginx as proxy server and proxy client.

[my-process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsA07.png)

Now, I stay in the first step, I don't know how to convert http1.1 request to http3, Do you have any good ideas about it?

I try to search about it, the solution is write the proxy tool that need to repackage http1.1 message and package http3 message to server. That's so complicated, I want use the ngixn to convert.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.